# Problems Using ActionBarSherlock in Project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock

For some reason, I can't get ActionBarSherlock to work. I think I have it set up correctly, but it doesn't show up in intellisense when I try to import it or use it. Is there anything else I need to do, other than include it as a module??

Images:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you add this library module to the dependencies of your app module? See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html.

Comment: That worked, but now I can't compile. It's telling me: `java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: resources.arsc`, and I can't find anything telling me what this is or how to fix it. It compiles all the way until the resources are packaged..

Comment: Please check that it's the only copy of the library in the dependencies, don't add its jars. It can happen because you have imported the Maven project with its dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to ensure that the dependencies are set properly, main application module needs to depend on the library module and there must be no duplicate dependencies on jars.

I've [prepared a sample project](http://www.sendspace.com/file/0g0ryg) using the demo provided for this library. Unzip, open `samples/demos` in IntelliJ IDEA, ensure you have Android Platform 4.0 defined, build.

Comment: Looks like the maven dependencies were the issue. IntelliJ IDEA is a great IDE, but it takes time getting used to compared to Eclipse. Thanks!