# How to import a Android Library in Intellij Idea CE?

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I have imported an Android project from Eclipse to IntelliJ Idea. The project use Android Library Actionbar Sherlock?

**My Question**

How to include Android Library Actionbar Sherlock in an imported project in IntelliJ Idea CE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the related questions:

- [Problems Using ActionBarSherlock in Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10626966/104891)
- [How can I add a "Library Project" in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8884662/104891)

The answer to the first question has a link to the sample project which you can download and open in IntelliJ IDEA to observe the correct configuration.