# Compiling samples for ViewPagerIndicator with IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

I am trying to build the samples for the ViewPagerIndicator using IntelliJ.

The current errors I am getting are like this (I get a bunch of those):

```
[Sample] ~/projects/ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-0/sample/res/values/styles.xml:19: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle'.
```

What I have done so far:

1. I created a new project using existing sources for samples
2. Then I went in the project structure, added new modules from existing sources for both ActionBarSherlock and for ViewPagerIndicator browsing to the "library" folders
3. List item
4. I made the ActionBarSherlock module to be a dependency for ViewPagerIndicator
5. I made both the ActionBarSherlock module and the ViewPagerIndicator one to be dependencies for the "samples" module

All of them are using Android 4.1 Platform SDK. I did not make any changes to the source code.

EDIT: As requested, styles.xml and AndroidManifest.xml for the samples is posted here: http://pastebin.com/YQxYy3md

Again, I did not make any modifications, the original source code is accessible on the website for ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: post styles.xml and AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @SardorDushamov the one from the samples ?

Comment: Is there  `<attr name="vpiCirclePageIndicatorStyle" format="reference"/>` in your `vpi_attrs.xml` file?

Comment: @SardorDushamov, yes, there is in ViewPageIndicator/res/values/ I guess this is not correctly referenced for the samples app to use...?

Comment: ? Sorry, not sure what you mean.... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually found the solution in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627940/347565

What I was missing was to check the "Is a library project" in the Project Structure... -> Modules -> ViewPagerIndicator -> Android

I guess that's the part that allows projects depending on that library to use the resources and attributes...

**EDIT**: To make sure I capture all the details, the dependencies are setup like this:

- *ActionBarSherlock* depends on android-support-v4.jar (and this one is setup as Export)
- *ViewPagerIndicator* depends on ActionBarSherlock
- *Samples* (for ViewPagerIndicator) depend on both ActionBarSherlock and ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 1):

Copy any resource:

`/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator`  in to `/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator`

`/library/res/color`    in  to  `/sample/res/`

`/library/res/drawable/vpi__tab_indicator.xml` in to `/sample/res/drawable/`

`/library/res/drawable-hdpi`  in to `/sample/res/drawable-hdpi`

`/library/res/values/`  in  to  `/sample/res/values`

I use this [source code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/tarball/master)

Comment: Trying now... but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using it as a library?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think that would work. I posted what (I think) the right way is to still be using it as an external library / dependency (would make it easier to upgrade when new versions are available and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Also import the library project that comes along with the sample project. It will fix it